# render template doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble with rendering an action from different controller.

I want to render index action from TagsController

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end
end
```

In tags/index.html.slim, it successfully returns objects from db.

```
= @tags

=>#<Tag::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff7c65ca060>
```

So I tried this code in users/new.html.slim.

```
= render :template => "tags/index"
```

It shows nothing. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: Please show the contents of the tags/index template

Comment: You render templates from the controller not from the views. So ```= render :template => "tags/index"``` needs to go in your controller action not in a view

Answer (score 0):

You render templates from your controller, not from your views. Like this

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
    render :template => "tags/index"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put,

```
render :template => "tags/index"
```

in your **controller** it will look for the directory and file like:

```
views/tags/index.html.erb
```

as you can render the data from **@tags**.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I just used before_filter method.

```
before_filter :load_categories, only: [:index]
 # your public controller methods   

private

def load_categories
 @categories = Category.all
end
```

I guess it's not the perfect way, which it's not calling an action from a different controller. I will try other answers as well.